# Maven clean package failure with Create Process id =2

Tags: maven, apache-spark, cmd

I'm trying to build Apache Spark to do this I execute `mvn clean package` (obviously in the spark root directory) halfway through the process I get a failure in the **core** file. The error log is as follows:

```
    main:
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] Spark Project Core ................................. FAILURE [ 12.363 s]
[INFO] Spark Project ML Local Library ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project GraphX ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project Streaming ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project Catalyst ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project SQL .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project ML Library ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project Tools ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project Hive ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project REPL ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project Assembly ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project External Flume Sink .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project External Flume ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project External Flume Assembly .............. SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Integration for Kafka 0.8 .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project Examples ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project External Kafka Assembly .............. SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Integration for Kafka 0.10 ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Integration for Kafka 0.10 Assembly .......... SKIPPED
[INFO] Kafka 0.10 Source for Structured Streaming ......... SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project Java 8 Tests ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 13.500 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-03-09T18:20:34+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 46M/498M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.8:run (default) on project spark-core_2.11: An Ant BuildException has occured: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "bash" (in directory "C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\spark-2.1.0\spark-2.1.0\core"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
[ERROR] around Ant part ...<exec executable="bash">... @ 4:27 in C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\spark-2.1.0\spark-2.1.0\core\target\antrun\build-main.xml
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.8:run (default) on project spark-core_2.11: An Ant BuildException has occured: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "bash" (in directory "C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\spark-2.1.0\spark-2.1.0\core"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
around Ant part ...<exec executable="bash">... @ 4:27 in C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\spark-2.1.0\spark-2.1.0\core\target\antrun\build-main.xml
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: An Ant BuildException has occured: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "bash" (in directory "C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\spark-2.1.0\spark-2.1.0\core"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
around Ant part ...<exec executable="bash">... @ 4:27 in C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\spark-2.1.0\spark-2.1.0\core\target\antrun\build-main.xml
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.antrun.AntRunMojo.execute(AntRunMojo.java:342)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\spark-2.1.0\spark-2.1.0\core\target\antrun\build-main.xml:4: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "bash" (in directory "C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\spark-2.1.0\spark-2.1.0\core"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExec(ExecTask.java:672)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.execute(ExecTask.java:495)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.antrun.AntRunMojo.execute(AntRunMojo.java:313)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "bash" (in directory "C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\spark-2.1.0\spark-2.1.0\core"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
        at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:620)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.launcher.Java13CommandLauncher.exec(Java13CommandLauncher.java:58)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.launch(Execute.java:428)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.execute(Execute.java:442)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExecute(ExecTask.java:628)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExec(ExecTask.java:669)
        ... 35 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:386)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:137)
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
        ... 41 more
```

Looks like the build_main.xml has a problem with the `bash` executable. The xml file below:

```
<project name="maven-antrun-" default="main"  >
<target name="main">
  <exec executable="bash">
    <arg value="C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\spark-2.1.0\spark-2.1.0\core/../build/spark-build-info"/>
    <arg value="C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\spark-2.1.0\spark-2.1.0\core\target/extra-resources"/>
    <arg value="2.1.0"/>
  </exec>
</target>
</project>
```

I did my research and found out that changing the exec to `bash.exe` might solve the issue but when I edit my xml file and execute `mvn -e clean package -rf :spark-core_2.11` same error occurs and the changes I made to build_main.xml get reverted. 
Thanks in advance.

**Update** - I couldn't find a way around it. I had to download the Pre-built version of Spark.

Answer (score 3):

I found one way around this problem, you can put %GIT_HOME%\bin into the "path" environment variable to use git bash.

Comment: Unfortunately I no longer have that environment to verify your answer.